# Проблема с наложение градиента на картинку (Background)

Tags: css3, html5, background

На заднем фоне картинка и поверх должен быть наложен градиент. Но градиент перекрывает картинку, если делать через RGBA, то цвет становится грязным за счет добавления асфальта. RGBA со значением 0.9 работает, но даже так существенно отличается цвет.
Прошу помочь решить проблему.
Вот код.

```
/*html*/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="header">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur</div>
</body>
</html>

/*css*/

.header {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 800px;
   height: 200px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(-53deg, #00b8d4 0%, #1de9b6 100%), url('https://svetvmir.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/8d5d1a1fb6eeb2615019bb1a3c4.jpg');
}
```

Comment: А какого цвета хотите добиться?

Comment: Тот который задан, если вставить вот этот код, то градиент просто перекроет картинку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это то, что вам нужно?

Разумеется, можно вместо opasity непрозрачность градиента задать при помощи процентов в самом градиенте. Я использовал псевдокласс after, чтобы разнести картинку и градиент по разным слоям.

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 800px;
   height: 200px;
   background-image: url('https://svetvmir.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/8d5d1a1fb6eeb2615019bb1a3c4.jpg');
}
.header:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  content:" ";
  background-image: linear-gradient(-53deg, #00b8d4 0%, #1de9b6 100%);
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="header">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Второй вариант:

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 800px;
   height: 200px;
   background-image: url('https://svetvmir.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/8d5d1a1fb6eeb2615019bb1a3c4.jpg');
}
.grad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-53deg, #00b8d4 0%, #1de9b6 100%);
  opacity: .5;
}
.header p {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="header">
      <div class="grad"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Почти, только чтобы текст был виден полностью, пробовал менять opacity, либо цвета не видно, либо текста

Comment: Вообщем для задачи мне нужно получить, вот такой фон. [ссылка](https://priscree.ru/img/4e86eb5afc6d01.jpg)

Comment: Или же лучше просто скачать фон уже с градиентом? просто это не совсем хорошо, если захотят изменить картинку или градиент

Comment: @ВладиславВерилов добавил второй вариант без after ))

Comment: Идеально, спасибо большое)