# Как сделать прозрачный фон, но не текст

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать прозрачный фон, а в итоге получается, что текст тоже становится прозрачным.

Как надо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... и как у меня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.info {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: #39312b;
}

.info-text h2 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.info-text p {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info-text">
    <h2>Декоративные покрытия</h2>
    <p>от лучших производителей</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: задать цвет фона с использованием альфа канала

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: задать цвет фона в формате `rgba`, где `a` - это альфа канал. Пример: `rgba(57, 49, 43, 0.5)`, где `0.5` это прозрачность `50%`

Comment: или так:  `#fead`

Comment: Посмотрите [второй вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1187941/Проблема-с-наложение-градиента-на-картинку-background/1187951#1187951) в ответе, может наведёт на мысли.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS RGB Colors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colors_rgb.asp)

```css
.info {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: rgba(57, 49, 43, .5);
}

.info-text h2 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.info-text p {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info-text">
    <h2>Декоративные покрытия</h2>
    <p>от лучших производителей</p>
  </div>
</div>
```